# Heat map of Belgium

Tags: geospatial

Is there a heat map covering Belgium? having enough resolution to be able to differentiate between houses would be ideal.

Comment: ....there most certainly are.....you need to be more specific. you can roll your own using heatmap.js.....but you're going to need a dataset to provide information to be "heated" in said map

Comment: ...and finding data available on a house-by-house level will be interesting

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/jwijffels/BelgiumStatistics, https://github.com/jwijffels/BelgiumMaps.Admin, https://github.com/jwijffels/BelgiumMaps.OpenStreetMap, buildings are available http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.shp.zip